# Wordpress Menu - Show Sub-menu on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, dropdown

I would like to hide the submenus and show them after their parents get clicked. At the moment I'm using a snippet I found on here, which unfortunately doesn't hide the submenu when loading. So I'm basically looking for an inverted solution of this or something completely else :)

The site: https://webnew.dpg-gruppe.eu

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#navmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
$('#navmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {

    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    $('#navmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#navmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add this line

```
$('#navmenu ul.sub-menu').hide();
```

after `$(document).ready(function () {`